# Change a div's content when hovering over another div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page set up so that there are several company logos set out in a 3x2 block on the page (mid-box-left).

When the user clicks on a logo, the contents of another div (mid-box-right) next to the logo block changes, loading 4 thumbnail icons representing 4 distinct sets of data.

What I want to do now is this:

When the user hovers over one of the 4 thumbnail images, it replaces the logo block with the contents of a hidden div (mid-box-right1) containing the information relevant to the thumbnail image selected. And when they move the mouse off the thumbnail, the logo block reappears.

Right now, clicking on the logo loads the content of the first div perfectly fine, but hovering over the image in the second div does not result in the logo block being replaced with the content from the mid-box-right1 hidden div.

I have it set up in the following way:

```
<div id="HiddenContainerOne" style="display:none;">
    <div id="mid-box-left1"><a href="#" class="testbox1"><-- content here --></a></div>
</div>

<div id="HiddenContainerTwo" style="display:none">
    <div id="mid-box-right1"><-- content here --></a></div>
</div>

<div id="mid-box-right">
    <a href="#" class="logo-change"><-- logo here --></a>
</div>

<div id="mid-box-left">
    <-- content here -->    
</div>
```

And the JQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".logo-change").click(function() {
    $("#mid-box-left").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#mid-box-left").html($("#mid-box-left1").html())
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('#mid-box-left');
        });
    });
    return false;
});

$(".testbox1").mouseover(function() {
        $("#mid-box-right").html($("#mid-box-right1").html())
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('#mid-box-right');
        });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Please define - `but it doesn't work`

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the post. Clicking on the logo loads the div contents for the thumbnail image perfectly fine, but hovering over a thumbnail does not replace the logo block with the relevant hidden div content.

Comment: Here is a working example of changing a div's content while hovering over another div: http://jsfiddle.net/LgNzK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are copying the html of the hiddencontainerone

```
$('foo').html($('link').html());
```

This does not copy events. So the mouseover event doesn't exist on the copied link. You should use `clone` or rebind your event handler after copy instead.

Alternately you could make use of `on` and monitor a higher level node for the mouseover event.

http://jsfiddle.net/jByc7/

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.testbox1', function() {
        console.log('mouseover');
        $("#mid-box-right").html($("#mid-box-right1").html())
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('#mid-box-right');
        });
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I shall do some reading in to clone, as I'm unfamiliar with it, and see if that works.

Comment: I've had a look into the .on solution you provided, to see if that would work, but it seems to cause all of the jquery to fail. I think this has something to do with Wordpress, as it is clearly working in your JSFiddle example.

Comment: I've figured it out ;D Thanks for the help ^^

Answer (score 0):

wrap yor jquery code with this

this check if the document has load all html elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your jquery code

 });
```

Comment: I've already got that in place. Forgot to put it in the original post. My apologies.